# Does Google Analytics SDK for iOS have SSL Pinning?

Tags: ios, ssl, google-analytics, man-in-the-middle, certificate-pinning

I am using Google Analytics SDK v3.17 from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download

I would like to know if this SDK comes with SSL pinning implemented. I already have pinned my backend endpoints to prevent Man in the Middle attack but I do not know if I have to pin also Google Analytics.

Thank you.

Comment: I have pinged someone on the team for you with luck you will get a response from someone who knows about the sdk directly

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo,
It is a bit difficult to comment on the security implementation details of the Analytics iOS SDK, as it has not been updated in a while, and as far as I can tell, there are no plans to release a new version of it any time soon.

Meanwhile, the Firebase SDK is most up to date and provides the support for Google Analytics. I do not believe there is any public information regarding the way the SDK is protecting against the Man-in-the-middle attacks. Chances are, the Firebase Support team can answer this.

Thanks,
Ilya

The Google Analytics Team